# The runtime classpath is likely polluted with duplicate and/or different versions of EL API

Tags: tomcat, constraints, loader

In one of the responses, it has been mentioned by BalusC

A common mistake among starters is namely that they copy the servletcontainer/appserver's libraries into /WEB-INF/lib because they got compilation errors in the IDE (javax.servlet not found and so on). Copying the libraries is the wrong  solution. You should rather have integrated the server in the same IDE and configured the IDE project to reference/associate the server in question so that the IDE will automagically take its libraries in the project's buildpath.

I am a starter and need to understand what am I supposed to do for the following statement.
"You should rather have integrated the server in the same IDE and configured the IDE project to reference/associate the server in question "

Thanks,
Arindam.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? How do you deploy your application?

Answer (score 1):

For my own projects, I use [Maven 3](http://maven.apache.org/index.html). It allows me to say:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.29</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The magic word is `<scope>provided</scope>` which means: Add this to the classpath for compilation but don't put it in the WAR!

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem solved by adding those jar file path in the classpathref in the ant script build.xml.
Set the path as follows: